# Are pandas DataFrame methods picklable?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, pickle

I am developing an algorithm to process a pool of datasets in parallel. I would like to examine wherther the DataFrame methods are pickable.

I wrote the code as the following:

```
import pickle
import pandas as pd

# Define a custom function that we will use with the apply method
def my_custom_function(col):
  # Do something with the col of data
  return col+1

# Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])

# Check if the apply method is picklable
try:
  pickle.dumps(df[0].apply(my_custom_function))
  print("The apply method is picklable.")
except:
  print("The apply method is not picklable.")

out:
The apply method is picklable.
```

Is this true?

Comment: That's not a method you're pickling there. You're pickling whatever the method returns.

Comment: How can I pickle the method?